# Definite integral of sine squared over one period

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I'm working through a textbook on Fourier series ("The Intuitive Guide to Fourier Analysis and Spectral Estimation: with Matlab", by Langton and Levin), and I'm a bit stuck on the derivation of one equation which is the integral of the product of two sine waves of identical frequency over a full period from time t=0 to t=$T_0$, which the book gives as:

$$\int^{T_0}_0b_k\sin(k\omega_0t)\times\sin(k\omega_0t)=b_k\frac{T_0}2$$

$b_k$ here is the coefficient or amplitude for this Fourier harmonic.

My integration is very rusty, so I'm not sure how this result was obtained. I have tried working it out by hand using this relationship from a list of trignometric integrals:

$$\int \sin^2(ax) dx=\frac x2 -\frac1{2a}\sin(ax)\cos(ax)$$

I assume that a = $k\omega_0$ in my case.

When I try to work out the definite integral, when t = 0:
$$b_k\frac 02 -\frac1{2k\omega_0}\sin(k\omega_00)\cos(k\omega_00) = 0$$

And when t = $T_0$:

$$b_k\frac {T_0}2 -\frac1{2k\omega_0}\sin(k\omega_0{T_0})\cos(k\omega_0{T_0})$$

Apart from knowing that the a sine and cosine integrated across a full period, $T_0$, is zero, I'm a bit confused as to how the term to the right of the subtraction sign "disappears" to give the neat answer shown in the textbook. Maybe the answer is self-evident from this knowledge, but I'm not sure if I've missed something else. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of $\omega_0T_0$?

Comment: Presumably the context of this discussion in the textbook includes the fact that $\omega_0 T_0=2\pi$.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah, I see now. I hadn't thought about that. Yes, since $\omega_0 T_0 = 2\pi$ then the sin term is always zero and the expression simplifies to $b_k \frac{T_0}2$. Thanks!

Comment: @McKendrigo Note that the first formula that you written is also valid for the cosine. Furthermore for both the sine and cosine you can use a integration interval different than $[0, T_0]$ for example you can also use $[-T_0/2, T_0/2]$ or whatever interval whose bounds falls in the points where the $sin^2(k\omega_0 t)$ or $cos^2(k \omega_0 t)$ have a maximum.